# Problem facing while counting number of input elements in document

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem while counting number of input elements in document,i have written some code but it does not seems to work,Please help me.

```
 $('#Q1_7_label').parents('TR').hide();
 $('#forwardbutton').click(function()
 {
    var x=$(this).find('input').length;
    alert(x)
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).find('input').length
```

will count the `input` elements inside `#forwardbutton`, which, given the element's name, is probably `0`.

If you want to count all, then select all:

```
$('input').length
```